# MacRuby (StopWatch tutorial) and Xcode: how to play with your app in Xcode

Tags: ruby, xcode, macruby

super new to MacRuby and Xcode. I just went through the StopWatch tutorial (https://github.com/MacRuby/MacRuby/wiki/Creating-a-simple-application) and all went well. Was able to deploy it successfully...or the build went successfully.

How exactly do I interact with the app? Do I need to export it or what do I do? If I click the start/stop buttons it's still in editing mode.

See attached picture:

[image: app is still in editing mode, cannot interact]

As I said this is my first time really messing with Xcode, so any input is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: When you pressed the "Run" button (in the top-left corner of your screenshot), the app should have started. You would have seen an app icon appear in your Dock, and a window should have appeared. If you didn't see that happen, then your app didn't start for some reason.

Comment: Gotcha, I took off the 'deployment' setting and just set it to 'StopWatch > My Mac 64-bit'. Working! This is awesome, thanks Kurt!